# Текст появляется над блоком,а не в нём

Tags: html, css

Есть такая проблема,что текст шапки появляется над ней.Для простоты объяснения посмотрите на верстку:

```css
 * {
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


header{
    height: 43px;
    max-width: 768px;
    background-color: #39A0ED;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 4px;
    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<title>Site_name</title>
</head>

<body>
   <header>
        <div id="header_text">
          <h3>Текст шапки</h3>
        </div>
   </header> 
    
   <main>
    <div id="block1">
    
    </div>
    <div id="block2">
    
    </div>
   </main> 
    
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: высоту у блока уберите

Comment: @MaximLensky Тогда сам блок исчез

Comment: момент....я проверю

Comment: @MaximLensky * селектор

Answer (score 1):

У вас текст внутри шапки, просто элементу `h3` назначен серый фон правилом, которое я закомментировал в данном рулсете:

```
* {
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   /* background-color: #f1f1f1;*/
}
```

Таким образом `background-color: #f1f1f1;` для `h3` перекрывал синий фон шапки.

```css
* {
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   /* background-color: #f1f1f1;*/
}


header{
    height: 43px;
    max-width: 768px;
    background-color: #39A0ED;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 4px;
    
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<title>Site_name</title>
</head>

<body>
   <header>
        <div id="header_text">
          <h3>Текст шапки</h3>
        </div>
   </header> 
    
   <main>
    <div id="block1">
    
    </div>
    <div id="block2">
    
    </div>
   </main> 
    
    
</body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: я даже внимание не обратил ... плюс поставил

Comment: @MaximLensky ^_^